# Github history of master lost after merging branch

Tags: github, git-merge

I performed a git merge using the following steps:

git checkout stage

git pull

git checkout master

git merge stage

git push

After this operation, when I go to github.com to view the commit history, instead of showing one commit of "merging stage into master", it is listing all the commits that were made directly to stage.

Now I need to rollback the merge from master but there is no single commit that I can revert back. Has anyone run into this problem and if so how do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this "merging stage into master" commit you must make a non-fast-forward commit when  you merge, e.g. `git merge --no-ff stage`.

Now that the merge is already done, you can revert back to the commit that was the latest commit on master before you ran `git merge stage` and do a new no-ff merge. There is no exact way to tell which commit this was, but check out `git reflog`, it will probably contain valuable information, or else you have to use your judgement and just decide where stage started.

Comment: I am able to use --no-ff to get the single commit in history. Thanks. Just wondering if this behavior has changed recently that git merge does ff merges by default. I did a merge two weeks back without giving the --no-ff option and I got a single commit similar to using the --no-ff option.

Comment: The fast forward merge has always been the default as far as I know. But ff is not always possible, so in those cases git will create a merge-commit.

Comment: How to "revert back to the commit that was the latest commit on master" ?